# Proof of the Curtis-Hedlund Theorem: Why is there a function $\mu\colon A^S\to A$ such that $\tau(x)(1_G)=\mu(x_{|S})$ for all $x\in A^G$?

Tags: cellular-automata

Here is the Curtis-Hedlund Theorem and its proof [the sets $V(\cdot,\cdot)$ used in this proof are explained below.]:

[image: Curtis-Hedlund]

My problem is I am not sure that I have understand that correctly. So I paraphrase it and rewrite it in my words in order that you can see if I got it. Could you please tell me if I got it?

**Here is how I do understand the proof:**

> > Let $x\in A^G$ be arbitrary. $\varphi$ is continious, meaning that for the neighbourhood $U=\left\{\varphi(x)\right\}$ in $A$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ in $A^G$ such that $\varphi(V)\subset U$. Because the sets $V(\cdot,\cdot)$ as defined below are a neighbourhood base, there is a finite $\Omega_x\subset G$ such that $V(x,\Omega_x)\subset V$. So for $y\in V(x,\Omega_X)$ (meaning $y_{|\Omega_x}=x_{|\Omega_x}$) it is $\varphi(y)\in U$, i.e. $\varphi(y)=\varphi(x)$.
> >     Keep this in mind. By compactness it is $A^G=\bigcup_{x\in F}V(x,\Omega_x)$ for a finite $F\subseteq A^G$. Set $S:=\bigcup_{x\in F}\Omega_x$.

I think I did understand it up to here?

The next part is not that clear to me; anyway, here is how I see it:

> > We want to show that there is a function $\mu:\colon A^S\to A$ such that 
> >     $$
> > \varphi(x)=\mu(x_{|S})~\forall~x\in A^G.
> > $$
> >     I think this means we have to show that for any configuration $x\in A^G$ the value $\varphi(x)$ only depends on the restriction of $x$ on $S$. So the author of that proof above takes two configurations $y,z\in A^G$, supposes that they coincide on $S$ and shows that for the resulting values it is $\varphi(y)=\varphi(z)$ (using that argument from above that if $y$ and $z$ coincide on the finite set $\Omega_{x_0}$ then $\varphi(y)=\varphi(x_0)=\varphi(z)$).

I ask myself: Isn't it a restriction to suppose that $y$ and $z$ coincide on $S$?

Maybe you can say me if my understanding of the proof is allright.

---

Notation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got it mostly right. The author wants to show that $S$ is the memory set of the local map $\mu$ of the cellular automaton $\tau$.

To prove existence of the local function $\mu$ it is enough to show that any two configurations $y,z$ which coincide in the finite set $S$ will produce the same symbol at coordinate $1_G$ when the map $\phi$ is applied. This then allows to prove the local map $\mu$ is in fact well-defined.

With this procedure you get the local map which produces the symbol at coordinate $1_G$ and here you basically used compactness of the space and continuity of the map. To extend this to a local map you use $G$-equivariance, i.e. the same map is used everywhere to produce the symbols at all other coordinates.

Comment: So existence of $\mu $ is just because for any $x\in A^G$ there is a $x_0\in S$ such $\varphi(x)=\varphi(x_0)$, right? And moreover, because for any $x, y\in A^G$ that coincide on S it is $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$, $\mu$ is well-defined. Ok?

Comment: Another question: Do you know the article "Some rigorous results for the Greenberg-Hastings Model" by Durrett and Steif? I saw on your site that you are dealing with cellular automata. So maybe you know it. If yes, can I ask you some general questions to it?

Comment: Your first comment is almost correct, however the $x_0$ should not be a configuration on the finite set $S$, but should be a point (element in $A^G$) from the cylinder set defined by the finite pattern $x|_S$ (the restriction of $x$ to the finite set $S$). The important point is to define the local map $\mu$ using only this restricted finite pattern, which can be done because the continuous map $\phi$ is constant on those cylinders (for $S$ big enough).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the paper you are talking about. I am more interested in purely mathematical aspects of cellular automata and symbolic dynamics and the title suggest this paper is about a particular model/application. Nevertheless I encourage you to post your question on stackexchange - probably there are experts around who can help you.